# how to convert multi-line dict to a single formatted dict? - Python

Tags: python-3.x

My code:

```
with open('C:\\Users\\d883531\\Downloads\\jira.csv',encoding='utf-8', 
mode='r')
jira = list(csv.reader(j, delimiter=","))
for row in jira:
    row12 = row[12]
    ab = re.findall(r'ab-\d{4}-\d{7}', row12)
    abc = re.findall(r'abc-\d{3}', row12)
    if ab or abc:
        ab_list = ab
        abc_list = abc
        j_dict = dict(zip_longest(ab_list, abc_list))
        print(j_dict)
```

My current python code prints out the dict like this:

```
{'ab-1111-1111111': 'abc-123'}
{'ab-2222-2222222': None}
{'ab-3333-3333333': None}
{'ab-4444-4444444': None}
{'ab-5555-5555555': None}
```

I want it to print the dict like this:

```
{'ab-1111-1111111': 'abc-123','ab-2222-2222222': None,'ab-3333-3333333': 
None, 
'ab-4444-4444444': None, 'ab-5555-5555555': None}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: Updated code

```
j_dict = {}
for row in jira:
    ab = re.findall(r'SO-\d{4}-\d{7}', row[12])
    abc = re.findall(r'SECD-\d{3}', row[12])
    if ab or abc:
        j_dict.update(zip_longest(ab, abc))
print(j_dict)
```

This prints:

```
{'ab-1111-1111111': None,'ab-2222-2222222': None,'ab-3333-3333333': 
None, 
'ab-4444-4444444': None, 'ab-5555-5555555': None}
```

But the first `None` should have been `abc-123`.

Comment: Can you show how you define `j_dict`?

Comment: @glhr Updated in the question.

Comment: You want to append all the dicts to a list and then conver the list of dicts to a dict.?

Comment: Thanks @SreeramTP. I've got the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`dict.update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) as follows:

```
j_dict.update(zip_longest(ab_list, abc_list))
```

to update j_dict instead of redefining it. Make sure you define `j_dict` before the `for` loop. This will have a side effect, that if you have a duplicate `ab` in an row, the latest occurence will be present in the final dictionary.

If you wish to have the first occurence, you can do:

```
j_dict = dict(zip_longest(ab_list, abc_list), **j_dict)
```

This leverages the [dict constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) capabilities:

> If keyword arguments are given, the keyword arguments and their values are added to the dictionary created from the positional argument. If a key being added is already present, the value from the keyword argument replaces the value from the positional argument.

Comment: If you use `update`, I don't think you need the extra intermediate call to `dict`.

Comment: Hi HodossySzabolcs and @Mad Physicist. Now it prints only `ab`. `abc` prints out as None even when there is a match. I have updated in my question

Comment: Ok, that's some new learning for me. But what if I need both occurrence? Just iterate through and create a dict of all matches.

Comment: Since you cannot have multiple occurance of the same key in a dict, you will need to store those values as a list.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks for that, I'll do a list instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're re-defining `j_dict` (essentially replacing all existing entries) at every iteration of the `for` loop instead of adding new entries to it. As Hodossy Szabolcs mentioned, you can use `j_dict.update()` to add new entries, and then print `j_dict` outside the `for` loop to print all entries.

Not that you can use `row[12]`, `ab` and `abc` directly. No need for `row[12] = row12` etc.

```
j_dict = {}
for row in jira:
    ab = re.findall(r'ab-\d{4}-\d{7}', row[12])
    abc = re.findall(r'abc-\d{3}', row[12])
    if ab or abc:
              j_dict.update(zip_longest(ab, abc))

print(j_dict)
```

Edit: an issue with `update` is that in case of a duplicate, it will overwrite existing keys. Here's a different approach which only updates `j_dict` if both `ab` and `abc` have a match, or if the `ab` key doesn't already exist in `j_dict`.

```
j_dict = dict()
for row in jira:
        ab = re.findall(r'ab-\d{4}-\d{7}', row)
        abc = re.findall(r'abc-\d{3}', row)
        if ab and abc:
            j_dict.update(zip_longest(ab, abc))
        elif ab:
            for i in ab:
                if i not in j_dict:
                    j_dict.update(itertools.zip_longest(ab, abc))

print(j_dict)
```

Comment: Actually, Now it prints only `ab`. `abc` prints out as `None` even when there is a match.

Comment: @Bharath see my edit. Here I'm assuming that `ab` and `abc` each have a maximum of 1 match per row. Let me know if that's not the case.